# Swift Alamofire Async Issue

Tags: swift, alamofire

new to swift here.

I'm trying to make an AF.request call inside another AF.request call and everything works fine.

The issue is that the `fetchAllUsers()` gets called after everything loads up. So instead of getting all the users right away, I have to refresh the page in order to get the `fetchAllUsers()` to execute.

I thought using closures would avoid this problem but it's still occurring.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
func fetchAllUsers(completionHandler: @escaping ([User]) -> Void) {
        let allUsersUrl = baseUrl + "users/"
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            .authorization(bearerToken: NetworkManager.authToken)
        ]
        
        if let url = URL(string: allUsersUrl) {
            AF.request(url, headers: headers).responseDecodable(of: [User].self) { response in
                if let users = response.value {
                    completionHandler(users)
                } else {
                    print("Users is empty")
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("URL error")
        }
    }

 func login(param: [String:String], completionHandler: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
    let loginUrl = baseUrl + "auth/login"        
    
    // Sets the Logged In User
    AF.request(loginUrl, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseString { response in
        if let data = response.data {
            let authTokenString = String(decoding: data, as:UTF8.self).components(separatedBy: " ")
            
            // Sets the authentication token
            NetworkManager.authToken = authTokenString[1]
            
            self.fetchAllUsers { users in
                for user in users {
                    if param["username"] == user.username {
                        HomeViewModel.loggedInUser = user
                    }
                }
            }
                            
            completionHandler(response.response!.statusCode)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass completion handler of main function and status code to fetchAllUsers and call it there after it's own completion handler

**completionHandler(response.response!.statusCode)** was being executed before **self.fetchAllUsers closure** because it was waiting for api response to complete. **completionHandler(response.response!.statusCode)** was destroying **self.fetchAllUsers closure** before it is executed, so I called completionHandler(response.response!.statusCode) inside self.fetchAllUsers after it's closure

```
 completionHandler(users)
 mainCompletion(statusCode)
```

Complete code works following

```
func fetchAllUsers(statusCode:Int, mainCompletion: @escaping (Int) -> Void, completionHandler: @escaping ([User]) -> Void) {
        let allUsersUrl = baseUrl + "users/"
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            .authorization(bearerToken: NetworkManager.authToken)
        ]
    
        if let url = URL(string: allUsersUrl) {
            AF.request(url, headers: headers).responseDecodable(of: [User].self) { response in
                if let users = response.value {
                    completionHandler(users)
                    mainCompletion(statusCode)
                } else {
                        print("Users is empty")
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("URL error")
        }
    }

func login(param: [String:String], completionHandler: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
    let loginUrl = baseUrl + "auth/login"        

    // Sets the Logged In User
    AF.request(loginUrl, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseString { response in
        if let data = response.data {
            let authTokenString = String(decoding: data, as:UTF8.self).components(separatedBy: " ")
        
            // Sets the authentication token
            NetworkManager.authToken = authTokenString[1]
        
            self.fetchAllUsers(statusCode: response.response!.statusCode, mainCompletion: completionHandler) { users in
                for user in users {
                    if param["username"] == user.username {
                        HomeViewModel.loggedInUser = user
                    }
                }
            }
                        
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello so the code works the way i want it to. Thank you. Can you give a short explanation as to why this is working and why my previous one wasnt?

Comment: sure, updated answer with explanation please let me know if any more questions @sameTbh